# How to get all distribution lists from exchange

Tags: c#, exchange-server, office365

I am trying to grab all of the distribution lists from Exchange. I am doing the same thing with Active Directory, where I am pulling the emails. I am able to do that using:

```
List<string> emailAddresses = new List<string>();

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://my.domain");
DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
dSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";
foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in dSearch.FindAll())
{
     if (sResultSet.Properties["mail"].Count > 0)
     {
         emailAddresses.Add(sResultSet.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
     }              
}
```

What would be the best and most efficient way to grab the distribution lists from exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using O365, you just need to use the API to read groups in Office 365. Here is an example how to do this: https://dev.office.com/blogs/GroupsRESTAPI . You do not need to use LDAP for that. Here is another example on how to read groups in beta endpoint using graph api: http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/group   - Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like the more I have read into this that I need to actually tap into the Global Address List contents to get the distribution list... Any idea on this?

Comment: The unified api provides an easy way to pull groups from your o365 tenant. you just need to build the request and you will get all results in JSON responses. You do not need any other EP to get groups in o365 tenants.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your help. This seems to work as expected now.

Comment: The first link is dead now, but I found it here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/groupsrestapi/